# filter two array with ng-repeat in loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am facing a issue where I want to display the all keys in a table cell but the keys which are already in my db will be displayed with different background color;  I tried with ng-repeat twice but it does not get succeed as it repeat the existing keys ;

here is [the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dG6kbS3NxXNbzpvC1VT7?p=preview) to get more understanding

and here is the relevant code

```
 d.keys = ['a','b'] // from database
 keys = ['a','b','c','d'] // complete list

 <span ng-repeat="vk in keys">
    <span ng-repeat="dk in d.keys">
       <span ng-show="vk === dk" class="key  {{ dk }}">{{ dk }}</span>
       </span>
       <span class="key">{{ vk }}</span>
     </span>
  </span>
```

Please suggest any better solution if possible; I read some filter method but didn't get the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you really just want to modify the class for the span I believe. Just one ng-repeat and then set the class with ng-class

```
<span ng-repeat="vk in keys">
   <span class="key" ng-class="d.keys.indexOf(vk) >= 0 ? vk : ''">{{ vk }} </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I need to lowercase the class name so I write  `? '{{vk | lowercase}}'` and it's works like magic